# Issue with AsyncStorage in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await

I'm facing with a problem when async/await keywords block other code from executing

Here is a simple example:

```
storeToken = async (accessToken) => {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken);
        console.log('Access Token: ' + accessToken);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
    }
}
```

storeToken - saves accessToken into AsyncStorage and then i am trying to print out access token just for testing purposes.

***console.log('Access Token: ' + accessToken);*** is not executing and I can't see anything in log.

> If I put console.log(...) line before await - it is working fine.
>
> If I am removing async/await - it is fine also.

Am I doing something wrong with async/await?

Comment: shouldn't you `await this.storeToken(accessToken);` ? (not saying that is the issue though)

Comment: i tried to use await for this.storeToken(accessToken); but it doens't help

Comment: as I said, not your issue in the code presented, and no way of knowing how `onLoginPressed` is used, so it probably is a non issue

Comment: it appears that `AsyncStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken);` returns a promise that never resolves or rejects

Comment: what happens if you `storeToken = async (accessToken) => {
    consts ret = AsyncStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken);
    console.log('Access Token: ' + accessToken);
    return ret;
};` instead

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: so, no `console.log` output? if you swap the `AsyncStorage.setItem` and `console.log`, then is the `console.log` executed? (opps, obviously you saw my "deliberate" typo in the previous suggestion, right)

Comment: exactly... if i swap it is showing 'Access Token: + actual token I received.

Comment: that makes no sense, unless `AsyncStorage.setItem` throws an error

Comment: seems like an issue - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12830

Comment: In  await AsyncStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken);   If you have defined a variable with name ACCESS_TOKEN or you are directly using it as a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an [RN Issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12830). Hopefully will be resolved by RN team.